# how to print just one index from the list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I need to print a number of the index from my list that diverd by some number, like 3.

The code snippet

```py
A = [4, 8 , 5 ,9 ,2]
a = 3
for n in A:
   if n%a == 0:
       print(A.index(n))
   else:
        print(-1)
```

it prints

```
-1
-1
-1
3
-1
```

My **question** is, can I get just the number 3?
Thank you all.

Comment: You may learn a bit more python and code in general before using it, because you need to undserstand that when code is written it's executed

Comment: You may think about accepting an answer now, or comment one to ask for something ;)

Answer (score 2):

Remove the part that prints the `-1`. As your code currently stands, it will print `-1` every time the number at that index is not divisible by 3.

```
for n in A:
    if n % a == 0:
        print(A.index(n))
```

Answer (score 0):

It can also be done by using enumerate() function.

```
n = 3
A = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
for index, element in enumerate(A):
    if element % n == 0:
        print(index)
```

Output:

```
2
5
```

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to add else condition if you won't require it really

so your code should be

```
A = [4, 8 , 5 ,9 ,2]
a = 3
for n in A:
    if n%a== 0:
        print(A.index(n))
```

else  you can do is this

```
 for index, value in enumerate(A):
        if value%a==0:
             print(index)
```